# Is it possible to set the keyfire in titanium commandline build for android

Tags: android, titanium

```
ti build --p android --T dist-playstore
```

I build android application like this but, it require android keystore file.

```
Where is the keystore file used to sign the app?:
```

I need to type my file path.

I would like to shortcut like

```
ti build --p android --T dist-playstore --key my/key/path.keystore
```

however can't find the right option, is there any option for this purpose ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation? [Link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Command-Line_Interface_Reference-section-src-35619828_TitaniumCommand-LineInterfaceReference-AndroidBuildOptions)

There are 2 options to do it, as per doc: `-K, --keystore <path>` So either `-K` or `--keystore`

Comment: Thanks I have checked another reference.